# Windows 8.1 DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE + Dump

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, dump, windbg

my Windows 8.1 machine started suddenly to crash with a blue screen and showing the error code DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE.  It usually fails after it wakes up from sleep or after it starts, it hangs up for like 2 minutes and then it shows the BSoD.

Drivers are up to date, downloaded from the Asus page (the latest update was on Dec 2013).  It's an Asus Ultrabook S56CA.

I've looked it up and if I open Device Manager I'm supposed to see a device failing, but everything seems to be working fine there.

Using WinDbg to get analyze the MEMORY.DMP, I get the following:

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe00000f8b880, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff8025a986840, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe00006668bd0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5215f837

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80000415000 pci

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFF8025A98DFB0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff802`5a986808 fffff802`58e6a1a6 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe000`00f8b880 fffff802`5a986840 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff802`5a986810 fffff802`58e6a0c6 : ffffe000`06226ac0 ffffe000`00fef730 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
fffff802`5a986870 fffff802`58d20f64 : ffffe000`06226af8 00000000`00000001 fffff802`5a986939 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
fffff802`5a9868c0 fffff802`58d21478 : 00000000`00000002 ffffe000`04fe53f0 fffff802`58f61180 fffff802`58f647e0 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x1d8
fffff802`5a9869a0 fffff802`58d7d478 : fffff802`58f61180 00000000`001ac2e4 00000000`0001271b 00000000`00012733 : nt!KiExpireTimerTable+0x218
fffff802`5a986a40 fffff802`58ccdabc : ffffe000`00000000 00001f80`00000001 00000004`9c6d4154 00000000`00000002 : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x148
fffff802`5a986af0 fffff802`58dc47ea : fffff802`58f61180 fffff802`58f61180 00000000`001a3fc0 fffff802`58fb9a80 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x19c
fffff802`5a986c60 00000000`00000000 : fffff802`5a987000 fffff802`5a981000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.16384

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_iaStorA_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_iaStorA_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_iastora_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {7d15649d-af9d-aeb2-1222-6fa8a2b3c912}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

UPDATE: Updated BIOS to latest version, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to fix it!

The problem was with the SSD storage, as @gtirloni [mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/804658/22571) that's a common issue.  If you are not in the country were you bought it (as me) or the warranty expired (as me), you can remove that SSD without any problem.

NOTE:  First try to update drivers, update the firmware to the latest version, debug using the Dump file. If everything else fails and you are tech-savy, go ahead and try to fix it this way.

[How to dissasemble the computer and remove the SSD storage.](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/disassemble-asus-s56c-series-laptop/)

Some highlights from that article:

> "Problem description: My customer complained that his Asus S56C laptop
>   with Windows 8 Pro OS on it started booting very slow. Reinstalling
>   the operating system didn’t fix the issue. When resuming from sleep
>   mode it was crashing with the following error: Power Driver State
>   Failure."

and

> "...removing the iSSD module fixed the problem reported by my
>   customer. The boot time went back to normal and it stopped crashing
>   when coming out of sleep mode. I didn’t notice any performance issues
>   with this module removed."

Answer (score 1):

`iaStorA.sys` is the Intel AHCI driver. Get the latest driver from [Intel.com](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=Intel%20Rapid%20Storage%20Technology%20%28Intel%20RST%29) and look if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I've found an update for that and updated it.  Hopefully it will work (crossed fingers)

Comment: you can also try to disable the powersaving for the HDD in the control panel: http://www.procaresupport.com/getdoc/cc78686f-ece5-401f-ac3d-bedaf845779b/Power-Options-for-Windows.aspx

Comment: Yes, updating the driver didn't work. I've reinstalled the computer and it still has the same problem. It has to be a hardware issue.

Comment: please make the change in the power settings

Comment: Thanks.  The issue was in fact related to storage.  Updating the driver didn't help because it was a hardware issue.  This helped as a hint on how to fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [common](https://www.google.com/search?q=0x9f_3_power_down_iastora_image_pci.sys%20site:.microsoft.com) issue. If updating iaStorA.sys does not work, take the machine back to have the motherboard replaced.

Comment: Thanks.  The issue was actually this.  I cannot take it to support, but I was able to fix it by myself.  This helped as a hint on how to fix it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on windows 8.1 and Enabled Hyper-v While my router connection is on bridge connection
while change the connection to auto problem is gone